# Display Google Search XML results onto site within HTML

Tags: 7, search

I have created a custom module to search the site using google site search and so far I have been able to get search results back in xml format and I need to have these results display on the site in HTML

Thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [Google Search Appliance](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_appliance) module for this.

This will retrieve the results as HTML and there are custom search-result(s) theme templates which will allow us to theme as per our requirements

Comment: Hi Sudheesh , This module requires a search appliance are there any other module with these same features that doesn't require a Google search appliance.

Comment: try this... it looks relatively simple https://www.drupal.org/project/gss